# Why nobody is answering my question?

Tags: comments

When I ask a valuable question nobody bothers to answer me. It has been a week since I posted a valuable question in this forum. When my question has some errors immediately everybody identifies it and reduces marks for me. But I have asked a valid question and no person cares about it for a week . I dont understand why this is happening
?

Answer (score 6):

The question *"What is procedure to let set path in wordpress?"* is about a 3rd-party plugin. Questions regarding 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here, as outlined in the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of the help centre:

> Note that **we do not handle** questions:
>
> ...
>
> **questions concerning third party plugins and themes.** As these required detailed knowledge of the workings of those plugins and
>   themes, support is difficult and with thousands of plugins and themes
>   available such knowledge is very specialized. Please consult the
>   appropriate support forum for the plugin or theme in question

Since your question is about a 3rd-party plugin, and a fairly obscure one at that, it's not likely to attract many answers. It doesn't help that it's a support question regarding the plugin, and not a development question.

This is not a support forum. It's a Q&A site focused on development, i.e. coding. If you are having trouble with a plugin that you didn't develop, you need to use that plugin's support resources.

Comment: Then create a separate stack exchange forum for wordpress plugins . Is that possible?

Comment: Feel free to propose one: https://area51.stackexchange.com/